# Model bind a subset of class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

I am trying to bind only a subset of a class's properties from an API request body, I am unsure how to achieve this.  If I could bind to a base class with only the properties I want to accept as input then cast it to the child class with the extra properties it would solve my problem but without serializing/deserializing that's not an option (i.e. can't cast from base to child).  Example class, I only want to allow name to be bind from [FromBody]

```
public class project {
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I could use a private setter on id, is that the answer?  I find that when I set id myself elsewhere in the application I get inaccessible accessor.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you should create a new DTO for the model you want to bind, applying [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and also is better for maintaining purposes. If you start inheriting from a base class, you will be facing later a huge problem if you need to change the contract of that class, like removing properties that you don't need and can affect the subclasses you have.

Now you can create

```
class ProjectWithOnlyName
{
    public string name{get;set;}
}
```

and pass that instance as a parameter of your controller

```
public void MyControllerMethod([FromBody] ProjectWithOnlyName dto)
{
    ....
}
```

I would suggest a DTO for each action you are doing.

For update

```
class ProjectWithOnlyNameForUpdateDto
{
    public string name{get;set;}
}

[HttpPut]
public void CreateMethod([FromBody] ProjectWithOnlyNameForUpdateDto dto)
{
    ....
}
```

For create

```
class ProjectWithOnlyNameForCreateDto
{
    public string name{get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public void CreateMethod([FromBody] ProjectWithOnlyNameForCreateDto dto)
{
    ....
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That would solve my issue, it does cause some doubling up of objects though.  Both classes would need to be updated if I were to add a parameter etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type converter as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)